# Showing a service's version in a dashboard in Datadog

Tags: datadog

Is there a way to display a service version (as a string) in Datadog? (Like sending an API request with the text to display)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, kind of.

It's possible to show single value on a dashboard (just use "Query Value" visualization), but it must be based on some metric reported to Datadog.

This is how it looks like:
[image]